# Why the attachment method does not work properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am having problem to run the method `.Attachment.Add`.

```
For i = 1 To 2

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen").Range("F5").Value = i
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

   .Item.To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen").Range("B6").Value
   .Item.Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen").Range("B5").Value
   .Attachment.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen").Range("B7").Value 'THIS LINE SHOW THE MISTAKE, "the object does not admit the method
   .Introduction = "RESUME"
   .Item.Send

End With

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
Next i

End Sub
```

It is necessary to attach the file according to the range value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `.Attachments.Add`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i add this line.
xArchivo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen").Range("B7").Value
  .Attachments.Add xArchivo
and check if the path was correct and it is but still got the error.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your post: I don't think that `MailEnvelope` has an `Attachments` property.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/infopath-form/aa943436(v%3doffice.15)

Comment: it has... i tried .EmailAttachment.Type xarchive but it does not work... maybe i call the method not properly or there is another way to call... thank you for your support.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372824/vba-loop-to-send-emails-with-attachments-also-includes-all-previous-iterations

Comment: Mr. Tim Williams it just work nicely...thank you very much!!! ;D

Comment: OK glad you sorted it out.